# Extrude Region (vertex normals)

Tags: modeling, normals, extrude

Hi I'm a beginner I just made a couple renders, and I really got into 3D modeling, so I decided to take a Hard surface Modeling course, I was following along and the instructor Extrude the vertices along the normal to give it a thickness.

Like in this image

[image]

When I do it on my side, this happens

[image]

any idea why is this? and if possible on how to fix it.

Added a view of my normals

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Also adding the .blend file
[image]

Comment: You have duplicate geometry everywhere, mind your modelling and cleanup your mesh

Comment: Looks like your normals are pointing in two directions, which suggests that your object already has some thickness, albeit a very thin one. So you're basically adding thickness which overlaps the already existing thickness.

Comment: Any idea why this happens? The shape is basically a extruded vertice...I have done it a couple times without success so there's definitely something wrong on my side

Comment: It might help if you shared a link to the tutorial you're following. Sharing your .blend may also make it easier to understand where and what you do wrong. .blends can be uploaded to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). If you do share your .blend, please don't forget to edit your question to include the link given once the upload to Blend-Exchange is complete.

Comment: You have a lot of double vertices (two vertices in the same location), so the faces aren't connected. They just look connected because they all have edges that are co-linear. Before the extrude region, select everything in edit mode and hit Ctrl+V followed by R. This will remove doubles, i.e. merge vertices that are in the same location. How you managed to do it like this, I can't say. I could post an answer about this, but I feel it wouldn't be entirely complete unless I can explain what you did wrong.

Comment: Basically follow the way is was in the video.... but I guess I messed up somewhere... I Just duplicated the vertex, and then extruded in the shape of the chair, then extrude again along the axis to give it depth.
@DuaneDibbley Thank you so much it totally work!...and yeah I'll delete it thanks again!!!

Comment: It's very easy, when extruding, to right-click, and think you've cancelled the extrusion. You haven't. You've only cancelled the _transformation_ of the new element (face, in this case). So the duplicate element is left there, invisible, coincident with previously existing geometry. If you want to cancel an extrusion, Ctrl-Z.

Comment: The "remove doubles" button is one of my favorite modelling tools. You can find it in the tools (left hand) panel of the 3D viewport at the bottom of the mesh tools section. Pressing the button will remove double vertices (within a threshold) of a selected part of the mesh.

Comment: @RobinBetts, Oh!, now that you mention that I mostly certain that might have happened, I will ctrl-z from now on thanks for the advice.

Comment: @TaviKohn Great! thanks, I would use it from now on, I'm still a newbie so any tips it's always helpful! thanks to everyone!